# Hight chart value are hidden , while clicking all legend

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use 3d pie chart , where I am having the 5 kind of data.for that I am using legend when we click the legend following value will be get hidden,since when I click last one it also get hide , in my scenario last value should not be hide, I tried lang:no-data its not working can any other way to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Updated my answer as per your comment, see the working fiddle.[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/wzyk5ypy/1/)

```
           point: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {                          
                  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                var legend = chart.legend;
                  if(this == legend.allItems[legend.allItems.length -1])
                  return false;  
                                    }
                }   
            },
             showInLegend: true,
```

[Here is the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/wzyk5ypy/1/)

Comment: This code is not supporting hiding the data values , it was showing which values of legend is selected.

Comment: @ArunPrasath see this fiddle , here if you are clicking on last item it won't be hidden. It was stated by me in answer as well , there I provided an idea to get it. I am updating answer as well. Hope it helps

Comment: -"above code works,but i need to hide dynamically ,you are doing last legend value got disabled default  , i am in need like among five legend any one should be disabled may be i can hide [1,3,4,5] or [4,5,1,2]"

Answer (score 0):

To prevent last visible point from being hidden through legend item click it is possible to check how many points are currently visible when [`legendItemClick`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<pie>.events.legendItemClick) would end up in hiding a point. If there are less than 2 visible points use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent default action of hiding of the point.

```
    ...
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function (e) {
                        // find two visible points to enable hiding
                        if (this.visible) {
                            var points = this.series.points,
                                visPoint = 0;
                            $.each(points, function (i, point) {
                                if (point.visible) visPoint++;
                                if (visPoint > 1) {
                                    return false; 
                                }
                            });
                            if (visPoint < 2) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ...
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smjtq7oo/1/

Comment: i need like this only but when i put **$.each ** its not accepting , and when i try to click legend, it has disabled

Comment: $.each(points, function (i, point) in this what the charcter " i"  in brackets depends , in my js its showing like unusable underline

Comment: @ArunPrasath [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is a jQuery function. `i` is not needed, so you can use second function argument directly instead - http://jsfiddle.net/smjtq7oo/3/

Comment: for me data will come dynamically in a string like(student,23:manager,30:)

Comment: @ArunPrasath If you fix your fiddle, so it will run the code and supply it with exemplary data, then my solution is working fine - https://jsfiddle.net/m67q0qdL/ or am I missing something?

Comment: $.each(points, function () {
                                    var point = arguments[1];
                                    alert(point);
                                    if (point.visible) visPoint++;
                                    if (visPoint > 1) {
                                        return false; 
                                    }
                                });

Comment: For me also working in jsfiddle , but when i try to test  the same code with **alert** message box - message box not coming while iterating the each, i dont no y ,i think as i said early $.each is problem

Comment: @ArunPrasath Alerts are popping up in Chrome/Win7 - https://jsfiddle.net/m67q0qdL/1/ What kind of browser and OS are you using? Are (multiple) alerts enabled in your browser? $.each is a part of jQuery lib, are you loading jQuery?

Comment: i also getting alert in jsfiddle but when i try to put in my application its not working

Comment: i am using linux aswell windows

Comment: @ArunPrasath What is the application that you are using? Are alerts enabled there? Because the problem is not visible in JSFiddle, then maybe there is some other JS code that is interrupting?